# PHP file print its own content

Tags: php

Is it possible for PHP file to print itself, for example `<?php some code; ?>` that I get output in HTML as `<?php some code; ?>`(I know its possible in c++), if not is it possible to actually print html version of php code with nice formatting and colors such as from this url inside code container http://woork.blogspot.com/2009/07/twitter-api-how-to-create-stream-of.html. OR from this website when you press code, while posting your example your code gets wrapped or whatever term is for that, makes it distinguishable from other non-code text. tnx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes.

```
<?php readfile(__FILE__)
```

`__FILE__` is a [magic constant](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php) that contains the absolute filesystem path to the file it is used in. And `readfile` just reads and prints the contents. And if you want to have a syntax highlighted HTML output, try the [`highlight_file` function](http://docs.php.net/highlight_file) or [`highlight_string` function](http://docs.php.net/highlight_file) instead.

Comment: Of course, you'd want to run it through htmlentities() and posiblely wrap it in <pre> </pre> so that it would display correctly.

Comment: So lets say if I wanted to print content of index.php from print.php , my code would be <?php echo readfile("index.php")?>

Comment: @c0mrade: Yes, that would print the plain contents (so the source) of that *index.php* directly to the client. If you want to print it in a HTML file, use `file_get_contents` instead of `readfile` and pass it through `htmlspecialchars` to replace HTML’s special characters. So: `echo htmlspecialchars(file_get_contents("index.php"));`

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure if this is exactly what you want but you can print a file using:

```
echo file_get_contents(__FILE__);
```

or syntax-highlighted:

```
highlight_file(__FILE__);
```